# How to embed a webview within the activity rather than opening another window

Tags: android, webview

So in my application, I use a webview to show some web content, I used a webview with the loadURL() function, however, the web page gets opened at another window, I want to show the web page withing the activity, along the other views and components of the activity

Update: SOLVED, refer to this post: [Opening webview not in new browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561709/opening-webview-not-in-new-browser)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening webview not in new browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561709/opening-webview-not-in-new-browser)

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question once I saw that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening webview not in new browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561709/opening-webview-not-in-new-browser)