# Android webview shows "open this website in chrome or mozilla"

Tags: android, webview

I want to open whatsapp.web in my android webview.
When my application starts it opens up the website perfect for a second and then says [It Says this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88hP7.png) 
Please help me to make this website work in webview...

Here is my code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView wv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String ua = "Mozilla/50.0.2 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Safari/537.31";

    wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    String url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/";
    wv1.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
    wv1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);


    wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wv1.loadUrl(url);
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561709/opening-webview-not-in-new-browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false;
}
```