# how to resolve unusual time delay problem in webview content loading

Tags: android, webview, scroll, delay

i'm facing a unusual problem while loading a webview with new content.

- Imagine a ebook reader app that im going to implement...
- app that allows the user to swap(fling) the screen backward and forward to see the chapter content(nothing but reading the book).
- Book that contains several chapters and i'm keeping each chapter in separate webpage
- when activity begins i load the first chapter in to the webview.
- i'm loading a new chapter as soon as one chapter ends (user is unaware of loading new page to web view he is just turning pages forward and backward)
- after first chapter 2,3,4 ..n chapters..
- As going next chapter i need to allow the user to come to previous chapter.
- in some condtion imagine if user finishes chapter 1 and come to chapter 2 . but user may want refer back to **previous page**. Then i should load the chapter 1.
- i can do that by loading previous chapter. but the content that is visible to user **should not be the beginning** of the chapter it **should be end** of the chapter. So im scrolling up to end of chapter see the end of below code. But logic not working ..

  ```
   public void fling(...){
   //swap forward
      if (end_of_page==false)
         scrollBy(480); 
      else if (end_of_page==true)
         webview.Load(); //load next chapter
  //swap backward
         if beginning_of_chapter==true && previous_chapter_exists==true
      webview.Load();  //load previous chapter 
      scrollBy(10000); //Scroll up to 10000 px so that i can get end of chapter
  ```

  But **Problem** here is the webview will not scrolls upto 10000px. bcoz the statement **scrollBy(10000);** executes before the previous chapter is loaded into webview (i.e bcoz of delay in webview loading).

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [onPageFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) to do processing after the page is loaded.

Comment: @Rajath DSouza its a method no? how can use that?

Comment: You need to override this method in your subclassed `WebViewClient`.

Comment: My guess is it shouldn't make a difference. Have you tried it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483030/need-help-changing-from-stock-android-browser-to-webview/5483116#5483116

Comment: Rajath DSouza i placed scrollBy(10000) in onPageFinished()  but it is not working...same problem it not scrolling up to last

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065134/is-there-a-listener-for-when-the-webview-displays-its-content/4945875#4945875